# VSCode never opens the correct folder, but instead just System32

Tags: node.js

I am using Windows 10 with Ubuntu integrated into it, using the Microsoft Store.

In Ubuntu i made a dir, cd'd into it, and i tried to open it using code .

I followed the exact guide; **https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-tutorial**

```
mkdir hello
cd hello
code .
```

But whenver i actually `code .` into it, it opens VScode with the System32 folder, instead of the "Hello" folder.

What am i doing wrong? I can't seem to find anything on google either.

[image: 1]

Edit: I just completely reinstalled Ubuntu - It didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this problem with Sublime-Text on a fresh install of Ubuntu.
I resolved this issue by removing the session located at `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Local/Session.sublime_session`.

I'm not an user of VSCode for now, but i'm quite sure it is similar. Try locating some not necessery files under `.config/code` (if so named ), probably under `Cache/` or `Local/` or something else, and delete without regret files which are named by something suspicious about your session/cache.

Hope this can help.

Comment: I guess i'll try to reinstall Ubuntu. I'd hoped for a solution that would've been a bit easier

Comment: Update: reinstalled ubuntu, but no changes. Should i try reinstalling VSCode aswell? -- Also reinstalled VSCode, no difference.

Comment: Then it should be another issue. I suppose VSCode is installed on Windows ? Are you running a dual boot, a VM or something else ? If you are just running Ubuntu from the emulator of W10, it is possible that VSCode can't access your folders under emulated Ubuntu architecture, so it open the farest it can access ... Sys32.
If you are a regular user of the Ubuntu emulator available from W10 advanced settings, I highly recommand you to give a try to a VM or a dual boot.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem.  I installed the [Remote Development Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack) in VS Code and it fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you have any folder name between the directory location, including any bracket or symbol then remove it and try again, it should work